# Prevent grey status bar on Android app launch using React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have an Android app using React Native.  The app always launches with a grey status bar and I can't find how to prevent that.

In my `MainActivity.java` I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    this.setStatusBarToTranslucent();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         this.setStatusBarColor();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    ....
}

public void setStatusBarToTranslucent() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        View decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
                WindowInsets defaultInsets = v.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
                return defaultInsets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(
                        defaultInsets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft(),
                        0,
                        defaultInsets.getSystemWindowInsetRight(),
                        defaultInsets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());
            });

            ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(decorView);
        } else {
            this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public void setStatusBarColor() {
        this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#33000000"));
    }
```

This code successfully sets the status bar color and transparency, but it does so after the initial launch and you can clearly see the status bar as grey for a short period.

My app theme is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_green</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/CustomSpinner</item>
</style>
```

And my targets are:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
```

I have tried to set the `colorPrimary` value of the theme, but that didn't help for the initial launch.

Comment: the status bar color in android theme is colorPrimaryDark not color primary sir!  go into native andorid code open values folder and in colors.xml file you shall have the color primary dark there change it to your desired color code for the bar!

Comment: @Rizwanatta Yup, that was it.  Want to leave that as an answer and I'll check it :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar color in android theme is colorPrimaryDark not colorPrimary! **^_^**

simply go into **native andorid code** open theme

you shall have the colorPrimaryDark there change it to your desired color code for the status bar!